# Photo Competition 2022-03-28: Famous Buildings

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Famous Buildings

Any structure that is know relatively widely. It could also include not just buildings but structures such as tunnels, radio masts etc.

For example: the Eiffel Tower; Sydney Opera House; Statue of Liberty; St. Peter's Basilica; the Great Wall of China; Taipei 101; Sagrada Familia; The Mezquita (in Córdoba).

This theme was suggested by [damned_truths](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/128968/photo-competition-2022-03-28-famous-buildings?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on April 11, 2022 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, film stock, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

**Previous contest:** [2022-03-14: Freezing or Melting](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/128851/)
**Next contest:** [2022-04-11: Claustophobic](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/129081/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Statue of Liberty at Winter Dusk
[image]

The Statue of Liberty near dusk on a February afternoon in 2013, as seen through some fencing near the Staten Island Ferry terminal.

Canon EOS 400D
100-300mm zoom @ 250mm
1/500, f/10

Answer (score 8):

### **St. Peter's Basilica**

[image]

iPhone X, 28 mm, f1.8, ISO 25, 1/3003s

St. Peter's Basilica in the Vatican as seen through a window in Castel Sant'angelo in Rome. May 2019

Answer (score 7):

**Three Architectures**

[image]

Some years ago I saw a theme on some social medium to try photographing three different types of architecture in the same photo, so I thought I'd try that.  It turns out there are a lot of possibilities in Manhattan (as opposed to the small town I grew up in...)

I snapped this one in March of 2013.  In keeping with the theme of "famous buildings" the one that's on the very left of the photo is the Empire State Building.  Just not the top portion that's instantly recognizable.

Canon EOS 400D
100-300mm @ 100mm
1/320, f/8

Answer (score 6):

**The Eiffel Tower**
[image: The Eiffel Tower]

Nikon D40, 30mm, ƒ/4.2, 1/3200, ISO200

Answer (score 6):

**Taj Mahal** in Agra, India

[image: Taj Mahal]

iPhone 5s, 29mm, ISO32, 1/5000s, f2.2
Jan/30, 2019

Answer (score 5):

## The Vatican

[image: The Vatican]

Camera: Panasonic Lumix GX80

f:20

ss:1/200th

52mm

iso:200

Answer (score 3):

### **Trevi Fountain**

[image]

iPhone X, 28mm, f1.8, ISO 20, 1/1171s

Trevi Fountain and its backdrop, Palazzo Poli, in Rome, Italy. May 2019

Answer (score 2):

The **Hallgrímskirkja** in Reykjavík, Iceland.

[image: Hallgrímskirkja]

iPhone7, 28mm, ISO 20, 1/1400s, f 1.8
Take on Jun/4, 2021